# PayPal guest payments outside US

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need to process payments from customers who have credit cards, but not necessarily a PayPal account - and they need not be required to sign up for PayPal either. From what I have found in the docs so far, it seems I need so-called Adaptive Payments to do that. Does this work with the REST API and can I do this outside the US (I live in Austria)?

Answer (score 0):

Both PayPal Payments Standard and PayPal Express Checkout support guest transactions; you really don't need Adaptive Payments for this.

I suggest you take a look at the [Express Checkout documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/express-checkout/), including the [Getting Started guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) we have available.

Comment: Thanks. Now I just read that a Pro account is required for guest transactions outside US. Is this documentation up-to-date? (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments)

Comment: Are there other requirements I should be aware of? eg. PCI compliance?

Comment: If you use the PayPal REST APIs for accepting credit card payments, you handle card data directly and will need to ensure you are PCI compliant. If you want, you can store card details directly with us in the /vault call: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#vault